# Correct context to use within callbacks

Tags: android, callback, android-asynctask, android-context

The title pretty much says it all. If you have a callback from one class to another and need to call some method from within the callback that requires a context what is the correct context to use? A common example would be an `AsyncTask` with a callback to the `Activity` or `Fragment` that used it.

I generally try to avoid using `getApplicationContext()` but I cannot use `this` as the context from within a callback. Is this a case where using a broader context is appropriate?

To clarify further I'm thinking of a callback with an interface between an AsyncTask and an activity. Once I'm inside the overridden interface method I can't get the activities context from within there.

Comment: what do you mean by " nothing is letting you use `this`"

Comment: I mean if I needed a context for something within an activity I could just use this as a context. For a fragment, I'd use getActivity().

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the Activity's context. Example:

```
MyAsyncTask mat = new MyAsyncTask(this);
```

MyAsyncTask contructor:

```
public MyAsyncTask(MyActivity context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

To call MyActivity's method `methodToCall()` from within `MyAsyncTask`:

```
((MyActivity)mContext).methodToCall();
```

**Edit 1:**

I am guessing your problem is this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);

        b = (Button) findViewById(...);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button newButton = new Button(this);        // Won't work!!
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Workaround:

- Declare a method in MyActivity: `getContext()`

  ```
  public Context getContext() {
      return (Context)this;
  }

  b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Button newButton = new Button(getContext());    // Will work
      }
  });
  ```
- Use `MyActivity.this` in place of `this`.
- Another way is to state that MyActivity implements the interface:

  ```
  public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

      ....
      ....

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Button newButton = Button (this)                // Will Work
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: If I have a callback to the activity using an interface - what would I use within that method? Once I override the interface method I can't get the activities context unless  or the AsyncTask context without passing that through the interface as well can I?

Comment: @Rarw I find your comment a bit confusing. So, let's say Activity A implements View.OnClickListener. Activity A then defines the `onClick(View)` method. Are you asking if you can use Activity A's context (or its methods) inside `onClick(View)`? If this was not your question, could you may be use an example to explain it?

Comment: @Rarw From your edit to the question, I think I know what you are getting at. See Edit 1 above.

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

It is a topic aber "leaks". Firstly the Activity to be passed is not good. According to some other suggestions that people should use getApplication or getApplicationContext. But you can use WeakReference for your wrapper, i.e:

```
static class X {
   WeakReference<Activity> context;
   X(Activity context) {
       this.context = new  WeakReference<Activity>(context);
   }
 }
```

Remember use static to mark your class, it could avoid potential "this" to your host Activity.

Might have given you some suggestions, might nothing :)