# Android ondraw context issue when called from separate class

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-context, redraw

I'm new to all this, and as you can probably tell by my question, I'm getting very spun in circles after reading all I could find on this.  Please help.

I have a ClassA that contains an inner ViewClass that extends view.  From ClassA, I call DialogCreator Class that extends ClassA and displays a dialog.  From the dialog listview, you can select an item that needs the ViewClass to redraw.  No matter how I send context, I get a null pointer context error.

ClassA constructor:

```
public class ClassA extends Basclass{ // Baseclass extends Activity
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      context = this;
   }
```

ClassA relevant code:

```
// Coming in from Menu for deleting or changing database tables
DialogCreator dc = new DialogCreator(context, id);
dc.onCreateDialog(title, list, mode);

    protected class ViewClass extends View{
         // Constructor
        public ViewClass(Context context){
             super(context); // Mainly crashes HERE
        }
           // Initializes rects, then draws via an OnDraw method
   }
```

DialogCreator constructor:

```
public class DialogCreator extends ClassA {
    DialogCreator(Context context, int dialogID){
     this.context = context;
     this.dialogID = dialogID;
}
}
```

Inside DialogCreator:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(String title, final ArrayList list, final String mode) {
   // build alertdialog listView
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       // User choices, etc... 
       ViewClass v = new ViewClass(context);
       setContentView(v); 
   }
}
```

Alternate OnCreateDialog would not try to setContentView... it calls a method in ClassA that tries to set it.  Both fail.

I've tried passing the activity into DialogCreator, I've tried using the getXcontext() from both classes.  I've even tried to stick a method in the ClassA that is called from DialogCreator class that uses the ClassA context.  Clearly I am missing a very important understanding of context somewhere.  Every way I try to define context, I crash with similar error as per LogCat below:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
```

I'd be grateful for an unspin in the right direction.

Everything works perfectly if I keep all the code in the ClassA.  Once I move the call to redraw into the DialogCreator, I get the context errors.

Comment: can you show your ClassA code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me all day, but found the answer thanks to [Correct context to use within callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240779/correct-context-to-use-within-callbacks).  @Vikram had it right in a somewhat related question about context in callbacks.  The answer to my question was to use the original Activity's context by casting it.

```
((ClassA)context).methodToCall();
```

where methodToCall comes from the onItemClick() of DialogCreator, instead of calling the redraw directly.

I would never have figured out that casting.